# How to create a NSManagedObject in a modal view using SwiftUI?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How does one create a new ManagedObject (MO) in a modal view using SwiftUI?

Running into a strange bug where Xcode consumes GBs of memory and fills up the hard drive on the mac through swap files.

When one creates the Modal view in the `.sheet` modifier there appears to be some kind of infinite loop created that fills the memory with duplicates of the ManagedObject that is injected into that Modal view.

This sample project illustrates at least part of the issue. If you run it you see the method called in the .sheet modifier fires over and over again. A theory is that the screen underneath that displays a list of ManagedObjects is causing some kind of loop between the two screens.

https://github.com/sphericalwave/ChildContextTest

Was hoping to use a childContext in the modal screen so any unsaved changes would be discarded if the modal view was dismissed without saving the childContext. But need to clear this hurdle first and there is some challenge involved in sharing ManagedObject across contexts.

```swift
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct CrtFdsUI: View
{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: CrtFd.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CrtFd.scale, ascending: true)])
    var crtFds: FetchedResults<CrtFd>
    @State var showModal = false
    @ObservedObject var absFd: AbsFd
    
    func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI {
        print("func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI")
        let cF = CrtFd(scale: 1.0, absFd: absFd, moc: moc)
        return CrtFdUI(crtFd: cF)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.crtFds, id: \.objectID) {
                        CrtFdCell(crtFd: $0)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("CrtFdsUI")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: PlusBtn(showModal: $showModal))
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.crtFdModal() }  //FIXME: Called in endless loop?
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the list of managedObjects.

```swift
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct CrtFdsUI: View
{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: CrtFd.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CrtFd.scale, ascending: true)])
    var crtFds: FetchedResults<CrtFd>
    @State var showModal = false
    @ObservedObject var absFd: AbsFd
    
    func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI {
        print("func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI")
        let cF = CrtFd(scale: 1.0, absFd: absFd, moc: moc)
        return CrtFdUI(crtFd: cF)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.crtFds, id: \.objectID) {
                        CrtFdCell(crtFd: $0)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("CrtFdsUI")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: PlusBtn(showModal: $showModal))
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.crtFdModal() }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the code creates a new instance of `CrtFd` every time the view hierarchy  is recalculated. That's probably not a good idea since the hierarchy might be recalculated unexpectedly for reasons you don't directly control, so that even without an infinite loop of creation you'd still probably end up with more new managed objects than you want.

I downloaded your project and I'm not sure what the two Core Data entities represent, but I did notice that when `CrtFdsUI` first appears, its `absFd` already has a value for the `crtFd` property, and that the `crtFd` property is to-one rather than to-many. That means that when you create a new instance in this code, you're replacing one `CrtFd` with another that's an exact duplicate.

I'm going to guess that you don't really want to replace one instance with an identical duplicate, so one way of avoiding the problem, then, is to change your `crtFdModal()` to use the one that already exists, and only create a new copy if there isn't one already:

```
func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI {
    print("func crtFdModal() -> CrtFdUI \(showModal)")
    let cF = absFd.crtFd ?? CrtFd(scale: 1.0, absFd: absFd, moc: moc)
    return CrtFdUI(crtFd: cF)
}
```

That avoids the problem you describe. It's hard to tell if it's exactly what you need, but since your code creates apparently-unnecessary duplicates it seems likely that it is.

Comment: Sorry it's confusing. It's a sample project because i don't really know what the problem is. Think of CrtFd as an instance of a food you eat (100g of Turnip). An AbsFd is the concept of the food (1 x 100g of turnip has a bunch of macronutrients associated, picture etc). So when you create a CrtFd the idea is you're logging an instance of a food you ate.

Comment: So an AbsFd can know many CrtFd's (i didn't make that relationship correctly in the Core Data model but i did just update it on GitHub).

Comment: the solution above isn't what i'm looking for because when you push the + button you're logging a new instance of `Turnip`. So i do want to create a new CrtFd and associate it with an AbstractFood. I just hard code the absFd to use because that way i can simplify the example project. It doesn't make much sense the way it's wired but it demonstrate the challenge of ViewHierarchy recalculating and causing a loop.

Comment: I see. It would have helped if your question included these critical details.